# How to remap a c header file

Tags: c, remap

I am troubling myself with the following.

I have a file foo.c

that includes foo.h and does some stuff.

The tricky thing is this one. I would like to remap foo.h to my_foo.h. So when the compiler sees foo.h it should go to my_foo.h.

One thing that could work is to include my_foo.h to foo.h. Any other suggestions?
No I cannot include in foo.c my_foo.h

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Why not rename `my_foo.h`, or create a symbolic link? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'd be astonished if this is possible. The preprocessor (which handles this) is quite limited.

Comment: is this an include "foo.h" or a include <foo.h> (quotes or brakets)?

Comment: it is an include"foo.h"

Answer (score 7):

Alter the include path to use a directory controlled by you before it uses the directory holding "foo.h"

In the directory controlled by you make a symlink called "foo.h" which points to "my_foo.h" as the target

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which system you work, you might have no symlinks.

But maybe you can create a `foo.h` with the following content:

```
#include "my_foo.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting issue.  I'd love to know what you're doing with it.

So if you have control over `foo.h`, here's a variation on a trick that is used when sharing header files between kernel code and user code in the Linux kernel.

```
/* File: foo.h */
#ifdef USE_MY_FOO_H
    #include <my_foo.h>
#else
    #define OVERRIDABLE_FOO_MACRO do { stuff() } while(0)

    int overridable_foo_func();
#endif

int not_overridable_foo_func();
```

Then in your Makefile

```
/* File: Makefile */
default: foo.c foo.h
    $(CC) foo.c -o foo

use_my_foo_h: foo.c foo.h my_foo.h
    $(CC) -DUSE_MY_FOO_H foo.c -o foo
```

BTW, this is not really a great way to form your Makefile, it just demonstrates the compiler commands you can use to switch between the two foo.h files.